# Is it possible to override a method comment but not the method?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, comments

I have methods `toSaveString(StringBuilder)` and `toSaveString()` in several classes and thought of turning those into an interface. The first method would always have to be implemented and the second I could `default` because it basically only calls the first method every time with a new string builder and returns the resulting string. (Not what `default` is designed for, but bear with me.)

Now I wouldn't need to implement `toSaveString()` in the classes implementing the interface, but I would like to change its documentation nonetheless to match the class. **Is there a way to achieve this** without overriding the `toSaveString()` method in the implementing class? Because adding three lines to call the default method or five to copy the implementation seems redundant and easy to get errors mixed in.

Also feel free to leave comments about design alternatives here, but the question stays because it is interesting in its own right.

Comment: btw the interface does indeed have a use case in my code. At one point I have four methods in my code being identical except that they call ```toSaveString(StringBuilder)``` on different classes. Very error prone imo

Comment: If you have a clarification to the question, **edit** the question and clarify it, don't write a comment. Delete the comment.

Comment: *Answer:* No, you can only write javadoc for a method by actually writing the method declaration, i.e. by implementing the method.

Comment: @Andreas I see you are a fun one. In your spirit, won't you post your answer as an actual answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Perhaps if you update your question he might :-)  However, questions whose answers are of the form "no you can't do that" tend to attract downvotes, and noisy alternative answers that either miss the point of the question or give inane suggestions.  (Your invitation in the last sentence will only encourage this ...)

Comment: I didn't expect people to downvote reasonable answers I guess... Or people with over 1,000 reputation be afraid of that. But oh well. And regarding the question, my comment does *not* clarify the question, it avoids comments saying "do you really need that". In what way would it clarify the question, anyway?

Comment: You would be surprised what some people will down-vote on.

Comment: A comment that prevents others from asking clarification questions like "do you really need that?" must by its very nature be a clarifying comment, so how can you claim the your comment does not clarify the question? --- Which of my first 2 comments did you find funny? Both are seriously meant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at the *javadoc* of the [`ArrayList#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

   ```java
   /**
    * @throws NullPointerException {@inheritDoc}
    */
   @Override
   public boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) {
       return removeIf(filter, 0, size);
   }
   ```
2. It overrides its *superclass* [`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

   ```java
   /**
    * Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given
    * predicate.  Errors or runtime exceptions thrown during iteration or by
    * the predicate are relayed to the caller.
    *
    * @implSpec
    * The default implementation traverses all elements of the collection using
    * its {@link #iterator}.  Each matching element is removed using
    * {@link Iterator#remove()}.  If the collection's iterator does not
    * support removal then an {@code UnsupportedOperationException} will be
    * thrown on the first matching element.
    *
    * @param filter a predicate which returns {@code true} for elements to be
    *        removed
    * @return {@code true} if any elements were removed
    * @throws NullPointerException if the specified filter is null
    * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if elements cannot be removed
    *         from this collection.  Implementations may throw this exception if a
    *         matching element cannot be removed or if, in general, removal is not
    *         supported.
    * @since 1.8
    */
   default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) {
       Objects.requireNonNull(filter);
       boolean removed = false;
       final Iterator<E> each = iterator();
       while (each.hasNext()) {
           if (filter.test(each.next())) {
               each.remove();
               removed = true;
           }
       }
       return removed;
   }
   ```
3. In your case, you can *override* only *javadoc*, and write something like this in the method body:

   ```java
   /**
    * custom javadoc
    */
   @Override
   public boolean customMethod(Object parameter) {
       return super.customMethod(parameter);
   }
   ```

---

<sup>See also: [Can I add code to an inherited method without overriding the whole method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66627494/15309136)</sup>