# Can I add code to an inherited method without overriding the whole method?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, abstract-class

I inherited a public method from an abstract class `X` but instead of overriding the method to copy and paste the whole content plus add two more lines of code, I would like to just use the code that is already in the abstract class without writing it all over again and just write the extra two lines. I've been coding Java for a little over a month and I haven't found a way around this so far, is it even possible?

This is the method inside the abstract class:

```java
public UsineOrganisme copieAUsine() {
    UsineOrganisme usine = new UsineOrganisme();
    usine.setNomEspece(this.nomEspece);
    usine.setEnergieEnfant(this.energieEnfant);
    usine.setBesoinEnergie(this.besoinEnergie);
    usine.setEfficaciteEnergie(this.efficaciteEnergie);
    usine.setResilience(this.resilience);
    usine.setFertilite(this.fertilite);
    usine.setAgeFertilite(this.ageFertilite);
    usine.setDebrouillardise(this.debrouillardise);

    //Ajouter les aliments de l'espèce
    for (String especeComestible : this.getAliments()) {
        usine.addAliment(especeComestible);
    }
    return usine;
}
```

And I want my inherited method in the normal class to be the same but add these two lines before returning "usine".

```java
public UsineOrganisme copieAUsine() {
    //Same Code but adding these two setters
    usine.setVoraciteMin(this.voraciteMin);
    usine.setVoraciteMax(this.voraciteMax);

    return usine;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in your case you just have to call the super implementation:

```java
@Override
public UsineOrganisme copieAUsine(){
    UsineOrganisme usine = super.copieAUsine();

    usine.setVoraciteMin(this.voraciteMin);
    usine.setVoraciteMax(this.voraciteMax);

    return usine;
}
```

Comment: In my case the first method is also inherited by another abstract class. I have the following hierarchy : 

1. Abstract class Organismes (which has the method I posted without the for loop)
2. Abstract class Animal extends Organismes
3. class Herbivore extends Animal

If I use " UsineOrganisme usine = super.copieAUsine(); " in herbivore will it override the method used by Animal or by Organisme ?

Comment: The `super` call will call the super implementation. If you override the method in `Animal` then that method will be invoked. If you don't then the method in `Organismes` will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** this is possible with the `super.methodName()` construct in cases where this method is not *final*. For example, you can override the *predefined method* of `ArrayList` as follows:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer integer) {
        // custom action
        integer += 1;
        System.out.println("Add number: " + integer);
        // predefined action
        return super.add(integer);
    }
};
list.add(3);
System.out.println("List contents: " + list);
```

Output:

```
Add number: 4
List contents: [4]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Is it possible to override a method comment but not the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66629025/15309136)</sup>